# how to render or display data in react useeffect hook

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

[image]

I am able to get data in react JSON object, now I want to convert the JSON to string data and display into the page, Please find the below screenshot.

```
export const QvcPollsTab = () => {
    
    const [spData, setSpData] = useState<string>();
   -------------------------------------------------------

return (        
        <Provider theme={theme}>          
                
                <Flex.Item>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <Text content={`Hello test ${spData}`} />
    ------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: I can see the json data as is attached in image, but i am not able to iterate the data and display individual field like fields values.]

I can see the JSON data as is attached in image, but I am not able to iterate the data and display individual field like fields values. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly bind the JSON object to DOM element. You have to loop through the list items & then bind individual property to DOM.

Check below article for detailed information: [SharePoint Framework: Retrieve and Display SharePoint List Items using REST API and React JS](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37948.sharepoint-framework-retrieve-and-display-sharepoint-list-items-using-rest-api-and-react-js.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Chandan, did you try my suggestions? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.